# Como imprimir uma mensagem de X em X minutos com JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Preciso imprimir uma mensagem de 5 em 5 minutos:

```
alert("que venham mais 5 minutos");
```

Como é que faço?

Comment: Você quer criar uma página dinâmica que escreva "que venham mais 5 minutos" a cada 5 min? Se for, isso deveria ser feito com JavaScript, não PHP.

Comment: Lucas Nunes, depende da finalidade... algumas situações requer alguma validação server side... aí não tem jeito.. Mas pode ser que o caso dele pode ser resolvido client-side. eu marcaria essa questão como ambígua, incompleta, etc.. carece de mais informações.

Comment: O que exatamente você quer fazer ?

Comment: Se for do lado do servidor pode usar um cron.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aconselho a você fazer isso em JavaScript. Seria algo parecido com isto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>jQuery timer - Codigos Fontes</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        setInterval( function(){

            alert('Que venham mais 5 minutos');

        }, 50000);
    });
</script>

</head>

    <body>
        <h1>Utilizando jQuery com timer: setInterval</h1>
        <p>Aguarde 5 minutos...</p>
    </body>

</html>
```